# Кая роль нужна чтобы запустить задание агента SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, безопасность, ssis

Пользователи из другого подразделения компании просят меня предоставить права на запуск заданий агента и SSIS.  Сейчас они даже не видят узел `SQL Server Agent` в дереве ssms - думаю, как раз потому что у них нет прав на выполнение.

Я хотел бы выдать минимальный набор привилегий для данной задачи, однако не вижу подходящих ролей sql сервера:

1. bulkadmin
2. dbcreator
3. diskadmin
4. processadmin
5. public
6. securityadmin
7. serveradmin
8. setupadmin
9. sysadmin

Подскажите, как выдать права на выполнений заданий.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Server Role to execute SQL Server Agent Jobs in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212598/5752652) от участника  [@TTCG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296074/ttcg).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212598/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Это не серверная роль, это одна из ролей базы данных msdb:

- SQLAgentUserRole - минимальные права из этих трёх
- SQLAgentReaderRole
- SQLAgentOperatorRole - максимальные права из трёх

См. ссылки на документацию:

- ["SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx)
- ["How to: Configure a User to Create and Manage SQL Server Agent Jobs (SQL Server Management Studio)" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx)

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212630/5752652 от участника  [@gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn).</sub>